# How to navigate easily in aarch64 assembly listing

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, arm64

I have an obfuscated *aarch64* (64 bits ARM, aka armv8) binary that I am trying to understand. This program decodes/decrypts machines instructions from its .data section, stores them into memory and then jumps to this address.

I am able to retrieve the machine intructions using the following gdb commands. As mentioned above, these intructions cannot be obtained using objdump because they are encoded/encrypted and the binary decrypts them at runtime.

```
set log on
x/2000i 0x****** 
set log off
```

This produces a `gdb.txt` file in the working dir containing an aarch64 assembly lisiting :

```
[...]
0x400ee4:   svc #0x0
0x400ee8:   orr x3, x0, x0
0x400eec:   mov w2, w3
0x400ef0:   mov w1, #0x1                    // #1
0x400ef4:   orr x0, x20, x20
0x400ef8:   bl  0x402660                    // Jump instr
0x400efc:   mov w1, #0x3                    // #3
0x400f00:   orr x0, x20, x20
[...]
```

I would like to able to :

1. **Jump to an address using a shortcut :** For example, I would like to able to click `0x402660` in the instruction `bl  0x402660` and press F3 to jump to the line starting by `0x402660`. I would also like to be able to go back to where I was using another shortcut.
2. **Generate a control flow/graph**

Of course, you can suggest any combination of tools/scripts that would work (i.e. if you think the best way to do this would be to import the listing in Excel and write VB macros, that's fine). However, keep in mind I have an aarch64 binary (so many tools are not compatible with this architecture) and that my binary decodes its machine code at runtime.

Comment: are you using ARM Foundation models or Qemu ? I'm trying to use gdb to debug a binary of mine running on the Foundation models but so far I can't manage to attach it the way I do with Qemu.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for this would be IDA Pro Advanced.

There is a specific stack exchange site for this kind of questions : https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

For your specific binary, it's not a normal binary, obfuscation is there to make the challenge more interesting :) ([for those wondering what this is about](http://static.sstic.org/challenge2014/usbtrace.xz))